# Database of English synonyms

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a database of English synonyms or thesaurus (text file or anything convertible to it or web service with [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)). Please, don't offer a word-by-word websites (like [synonym.com](http://synonym.com)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a list of APIs that can be used the following way to retrieve synonyms:

1. API call: `http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/{api key}/hello/json`

   The details are here: http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php
2. API call: `http://api-pub.dictionary.com/v001?vid=<VID>&q=hello&type=synonyms`

   the details are here: http://content.dictionary.com/api (Note: *"We are selective about our API partners and approve use as well as develop terms on a case-by-case basis."*)
3. API call: `http://www.abbreviations.com/services/v1/syno.aspx?tokenid={token}&word=hello`

   the details are here: http://www.abbreviations.com/synonyms_api.php (see also [its entry on programmableweb.com](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/synonyms))
4. API call: `http://watson.kmi.open.ac.uk/API/term/synonyms?term=hello`

   the details are here: http://watson.kmi.open.ac.uk/API/explain-syn.html
5. API call: `http://thesaurus.altervista.org/thesaurus/v1?word=hello&language=en_US&key={key}&output=json`

   the details are here: http://thesaurus.altervista.org/

Comment: Great list! The Princeton Wordnet website also has a list that might be useful: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#web

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067752/synonym-style-text-lookup-and-parsing) on stackoverflow; it has a lot of good information on synonym web services.